# Clickable footnotes/anchors should be a thing

Tags: feature-request, markdown, hyperlinks

Essentially, a link that can be made to reference another point in the same post, and clicking on that point leads the other way around.

However, you can only reference *your own post*, and not anywhere else on the page, and you will be notified if the anchors break before you submit an edit, so that you can fix them.

Comment: @Shadow Wizard, Isn't the other question asking for anchors that can reference the whole page rather than just *your own post*, a different thing and requiring a bit different implementation as well?

Comment: Not sure what you mean. It's asking to support markup like `<a name="mylink1"></a>` then you'll be able to link to that part in the post with `<a href="mylink1">click here to jump to specific part of a post</a>`. And from what I can see, that's what you're asking as well. No?

Comment: @Shadow Wizard, they seem to be asking for the ability to reference *every answer on the question* rather than *only their own answers or posts*, which is what I'm asking about here. The former may be more difficult to implement and might require different methods to achieve it.

Comment: Well, it's still very similar, so your suggestion can be part of the original request (e.g. as answer), I don't think there should be a separate request for that.

Comment: @Shadow Wizard. Similar yes, but anchors for all the answers is a very complex request that is quite different from simply having anchors for your own posts only. Both are so different complexity levels that essentially it's possible the implementations may be different, very different I would conjecture. It makes little sense to group them under the same question.